# Are there heuristics for prioritizing variable interactions to try to improve model performance?

Tags: classification, interaction, model-selection

I have a classifier model working with p predictors -- with a reasonable level of success.

I have tried my typical feature engineering tricks but the classifier performance is stubbornly stuck -- this has been a bit unexpected.

I want to explore variable(predictor) interactions to try to further improve the performance.

I don't have a good intuition how the variable interactions would play to improve performance.

The number of predictors is not small, thus the number of possible interactions is rather large.

**Is there any heuristic by which I can pick which interactions to try before others?**

For example:

1. Prioritize predictors that have low correlation
2. Prioritize predictors that have high correlation
3. Prioritize predictors that are monotonic and non-monotonic vis-a-vis some variable